# jQuery Validate On Remote response based

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

```
remote: {
  url: "/pages/",
  complete: function (status) {
      return !status;
  }
}
```

I have applied jquery Validation and remote parameter, the call returns true and false depending on the data sent, but I need the validation to be like if true is returned then it should be considered false and vice versa. I tried returning the opposite response back in the complete callback, but the validations do not work that way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be the status returned from remote will not be considered as `bool` here. So just try this.

```
remote: {
  url: "/pages/",
  complete: function (status) {
       if(status=="true")
          return false;
       return true; //no need of else
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I tried that, but it does not help, I even tried putting return false; directly in callback, but the validations does not consider the response

Comment: Just `console.log(status)` and see what you are getting! If it is a `jqXHR` type then you need to fetch it as `status.responseText`

Comment: I get true/false depending on the data entered

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.

So make sure you respond with a valid JSON true or false.

Then simply make a statement like

```
if(status)
```

or `if(status == true)`

But I would suggest not changing anything at that side. I would return true by the remote page if its false, as you suggested. You should not return true if its actually false.. so just change the type you call back.

Answer (score 0):

```
    remote: {
      url: "/pages/",
      success: function( response ) {
        var element = $(this).find(`your element`)[0];
        var previous = validator.previousValue( element );
        var valid = response === "ok" || response === "true", //add your valid condition here
                    errors, message, submitted;

        validator.settings.messages[ element.name ].remote = previous.originalMessage;
        if ( valid ) {
            submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
            validator.prepareElement( element );
            validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
            validator.successList.push( element );
            delete validator.invalid[ element.name ];
            validator.showErrors();
        } else {
            errors = {};
            message = response || validator.defaultMessage( element, "remote" );
            errors[ element.name ] = previous.message = $.isFunction( message ) ? message( value ) : message;
            validator.invalid[ element.name ] = true;
            validator.showErrors( errors );
        }
        previous.valid = valid;
        validator.stopRequest( element, valid );
      }
   }
```